# action in wordpress to template page

Tags: wordpress, templates, action

In my plugin I have an action in my form that is supposed to take me to a template page called go, but when I click on it wordpress tells me that it does not exist but if I refresh the page then it loads up the go page.  Any ideas why it wont just load normally and how to fix it?

```
<form name="trailer-bulk-waste-free" method="post" action="go">
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo"$date"; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pickup" value="<?php echo"$pu" ?>">
There is a bunch of other inputs in here but probably redundant to put. 
<p><input type="submit" name="CONTINUE" value="CONTINUE" />
```

Comment: Would you mind including some code in to help us see what you're dealing with?

Comment: I've also tried have action="go.php" but didnt work plus it requires a plugin to have a template end with .php

Answer (score 0):

An easy and straight forward way is to [assign the `go` page template to a page](https://ithemes.com/tutorials/applying-wordpress-page-template/). Let's say `ID` of that page is `77`, then do this.

```
<form name="trailer-bulk-waste-free" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink( 77 ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo"$date"; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="pickup" value="<?php echo"$pu" ?>">
    There is a bunch of other inputs in here but probably redundant to put. 
    <p><input type="submit" name="CONTINUE" value="CONTINUE" /></p>
</form>
```

Hopefully, this will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Okay sweet Ill give that a try where do I get or how do I set the page id?

Comment: It's the page ID that you created and assigned the `go` template to. It'll be generated automatically. [Check this for help](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/)

Answer (score -1):

Try it with another browser to see if it might be from the browser's cache.

Comment: Tried that and no luck with chrome or E